# How to play downloaded audio from network by react-native-fs in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I checked all audio modules and they work only with directory android/app/src/main/res/raw, but I can download only in cache or files directories.

Does somebody know what how I can play downloaded audio?

Answer (score 0):

May be this question about Images could help with Audio.

https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/issues/60

require() is a build-time directive for bundling resources with the application.

Look at the test project for examples: https://github.com/cjdell/react-native-fs-test